# Saving and restoring Activity State when Activity is closed by pressing back button by user

Tags: android, save, state

I am working on an App for collecting Customer Details like personal, business, assets etc.

The app shows a `ListView` with options and based on options Activities are started. After entering details in personal user presses back button and returns to MainActivity (`Activity` with a `ListView`) and selects another option like business details and assets detail. User enters the details and come back to MainActivity by Back button and selects another option.

I tried to save my `Activity`s using `onSavedInstance(Bundle)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)` and sharedpreference  but failed.

Can anyone help? I will provide code if required.

Comment: "I tried to save... but failed" what does fail mean here? it didn't restore the state correctly? the app crashed? it painted your hair purple?

Comment: check the onBackPressed() method.

Answer (score 1):

`OnSaveInstanceState()`/`OnRestoresInstanceState()` is not supposed to be used on a back key pressed from an Activity. In fact , `OnSaveInstanceState()` is never called.  Here the user is explicitly destroying the Activity and removing it from the back stack.

These two methods are used in case where user presses home button or in cases where Android System destroys your Activity.

The options you can try

1. Try using `StartActivityForResult()`/`OnActivityResult()` methods. Here the target activity can set data whcih can be accessed by your parent activity.
2. Use an application class(a single instance class (singleton class) for holding data).
3. Things like shared `SharedPreferences`, files, database, etc.